# Taking value from one module's class to another

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and i wanted to ask , i have 2 modules , and i want to get the value from one to another module. I want to take the "ids" value and use it in another module for printing on screen 
I tried to calling it from import but it does not work , and i am lost

class CoordinatesGenerator:
    KEY_RESET = ord("r")
    KEY_QUIT = ord("q")

```
def __init__(self, image, output, color):
    self.output = output
    self.caption = image
    self.color = color

    self.image = open_cv.imread(image).copy()
    self.click_count = 0
    self.ids = 0
    self.coordinates = []

    open_cv.namedWindow(self.caption, open_cv.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
    open_cv.setMouseCallback(self.caption, self.__mouse_callback)

def generate(self):
    while True:
        open_cv.imshow(self.caption, self.image)
        key = open_cv.waitKey(0)

        if key == CoordinatesGenerator.KEY_RESET:
            self.image = self.image.copy()
        elif key == CoordinatesGenerator.KEY_QUIT:
            break
    open_cv.destroyWindow(self.caption)

def __mouse_callback(self, event, x, y, flags, params):

    if event == open_cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        self.coordinates.append((x, y))
        self.click_count += 1

        if self.click_count >= 4:
            self.__handle_done()

        elif self.click_count > 1:
            self.__handle_click_progress()

    open_cv.imshow(self.caption, self.image)

def __handle_click_progress(self):
    open_cv.line(self.image, self.coordinates[-2], self.coordinates[-1], (255, 0, 0), 1)

def __handle_done(self):
    open_cv.line(self.image,
                 self.coordinates[2],
                 self.coordinates[3],
                 self.color,
                 1)
    open_cv.line(self.image,
                 self.coordinates[3],
                 self.coordinates[0],
                 self.color,
                 1)

    self.click_count = 0

    coordinates = np.array(self.coordinates)

    self.output.write("-\n          id: " + str(self.ids) + "\n          coordinates: [" +
                      "[" + str(self.coordinates[0][0]) + "," + str(self.coordinates[0][1]) + "]," +
                      "[" + str(self.coordinates[1][0]) + "," + str(self.coordinates[1][1]) + "]," +
                      "[" + str(self.coordinates[2][0]) + "," + str(self.coordinates[2][1]) + "]," +
                      "[" + str(self.coordinates[3][0]) + "," + str(self.coordinates[3][1]) + "]]\n")

    draw_contours(self.image, coordinates, str(self.ids + 1), COLOR_WHITE)



    for i in range(0, 4):
        self.coordinates.pop()

    self.ids += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code in a (python) file called myclasses.py and create another file in the same directory from wich you will import your (myclasses.py) module like this:

```
from myclasses import CoordinatesGenerator
```

Don't forget to add a file called `__init__.py` to this folder so Python knows it as a directory. Otherwise your imports will fail!

Conclusion:
You every folder from wich you try to import modules requires a `__init__.py` file. So in the example above you would have one folder containing 3 files

Comment: Mhmm , i see , because i am getting an error when i try to print the values "ids is not defined" and i tried this "from coordinates_generator import *" and it worked i think , it does not give me an error but still getting thee not defined problem

Comment: That import line should work as well! The error 'ids is not defined' sounds more like something went wrong when creating the instance of the class.

Comment: So actually i am doing it right ? it theory it should work like that right ? because i am new to python and still learning

Comment: For what I can tell there is nothing wrong with your way of importing things. Since your not running into that kind of errors. 

The other error message 'ids is not defined' is a different issue that states the a property of your object/class instance is not set. It's a different topic/issue than what you've posted here i believe. Perhaps you can show the code of how you're creating this instance.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help , i managed somehow to fix this problem :D it turns out that i was doing something else wrong